# Excluding tests from being run in IntellIJ

Tags: java, maven, junit, intellij-idea

Is it no option to exclude some tests in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate? I want to run unit tests in IntelliJ but exclude the integration tests. I name the integration tests with `*IT.java` so the Maven failsafe plugin can run them seperatly from the unit tests.

Answer (score 136):

In the `JUnit` Run configuration set the `Test kind` to **Pattern**, specify the following regular expression as the pattern:

```
^(?!.*IT$).*$
```

It matches against the class name, so you don't need to match `.java` extension. Regular expression will not match if the class name ends with `IT` using the [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

[image: ignore tests ending with IT]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This works fine in IDEA, but causes all tests to be skipped under TeamCity. It seems that TeamCity 8.0.4 doesn't honor Pattern configurations at all. Should I file an issue?

Comment: Use pattern `^(?!(.*SlowTest$|.*SlowSpec$)).*$`  to omit both slow Junit tests and Spock tests named with convention of `.*SlowTest` and `.*SlowSpec`

Comment: btw, regex can be simplified to `.*(?<!IT)$`

Answer (score 20):

With JUnit5, you can now tag your tests, e.g: `@Tag("integration-test")`.

Also, given IntelliJ supports now JUnit5 as well, you can then create a **JUnit Test Configuration** and select **Test Kind**: `Tags (JUnit5)`.

To exclude let's say "integration-test", you just need to specify as tags:
`!integration-test`, and IntelliJ will run all your JUnit5 tests except the ones tagged with `integration-test`.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50958900/4071001) for details (including screenshot).

Answer (score 3):

I would split them to that they are in different packages. They are doing different things after all. You can then run your tests per package. [This](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-junit.html) link details how to do this.