# Why doesn't this negative lookahead work the way I expect?

Tags: regex

I was looking at this [answer to a stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104807/61624).  It said to use this regex to exclude a certain test with a name pattern that contains "IT":

```
^(?!.*IT$).*$
```

In my case, I'm trying to exclude a class with the name of "RestIntegrationTestRunner".  I tried writing a regex like this:

```
^.*(?!RestIntegrationTestRunner).*$
```

But, this didn't exclude that test.  I had to do this:

```
^(?!.*RestIntegrationTestRunner).*$
```

Why doesn't it work the first way?  I interpret the first example to mean this: Use any classes that start with anything, but *don't* contain `RestIntegrationTestRunner` in the name.

I interpret the second regex to be saying pretty much the same thing: Don't use any classes that start with anything and contain `RestIntegrationTestRunner`.

So why does only the second one exclude the "RestIntegrationTestRunner" class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first regex will match any string. This is because the first `.*` can match the whole string, and the remaining empty string isn't equal to `RestIntegrationTestRunner`, thus the negative look-ahead succeeds, and the second `.*` matches the empty string.

The second regex however matches diffierently: First, it matches any string due to the second `.*`, but then the string is checked for whether it matches `.*RestIntegrationTestRunner`, i.e. whether it contains RestIntegrationTestRunner, and fails if it does.

Comment: I understand the first paragraph.  In your second: "it matches any string due to the second .*, but then the string is checked for whether it matches"  Are you sure that's the way it works?  I would have assumed it checks the string left to right, and by that time it's already "pass/failed" the contents in the negative lookahead.

Comment: @tieTYT that's not exactly how it works, but in this case this is how it turns out to be (because the look-ahead is at the beginning). I cannot easily describe the actual process, e.g. an explanation would be that a regex just blindly tries to match whatever it can and returns the longest match it found. That will actually return the correct value, but is definitely not how a regex works because it is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*(?!RestIntegrationTestRunner).*$
```

means:

- start with anything, including empty string (greedy)
- followed(negative look ahead)**`.*`** (allows empty too)

that is, the 2nd part doesn't make much sense. For example, if you want to exclude `Foo`:

four cases:

```
xxxFoo
xxxFooyyy
FooFoo
Foo
```

will be all matched.

Because the whole string matches the first part: **greedy** match anything. And your 2nd part, the `(?!...).*` allows empty, so it doesn't affect the result.

In fact, this regex would match your needs:

```
^((?!RestIntegrationTestRunner).)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

`^.*(?!RestIntegrationTestRunner).*$`

The negative look ahead is placed after the initial .* which will match your entire string (up until a newline).  If you're going to begin with a .* you would remove the second .* and use a negative look behind:  `^.*(?<!RestIntegrationTestRunner)$`

Comment: Since a regex will always try to match if possible, a non-greedy modifier to the first * won't change much, won't it?

Comment: That makes it lazy, so it will match as little as possible.  It's worth noting that this will always be nothing, so it might as well not be there (as in the OP's second regex).

Comment: Lazy doesn't mean that it won't match anything, as otherwise non-greedy modifiers would just be equivalent to `{0}` to match as little as possible, i.e. the empty string. Non-greedy just means that it will try to match the least characters possible for the regex to match the string, instead of the most.

Comment: My attempts to change 'nothing' to 'empty string' took too long and would still have been incorrect.  I think you're correct on the not changing anything as well.  I should probably be somewhere that I can test before posting answers in the future!