# Pattern Usage in Intellij run configurations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I'm looking for a way to create a run configuration in intellij that runs all my unit tests but ignores all my functional tests.

If I simply use a run configuration that "Tests all in Package" and leave the Package field blank it runs both unit and functional across all modules in the project.

All my junit functional tests in each module are in src/main/java.
All my junit unit tests are in src/test/ for each module.
So the two types can be distinguished by path.
The two types of tests share the same naming pattern and they are also in the same java package. So can't exclude by either of the unaccepted answers  described in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104357/excluding-tests-from-being-run-in-intellij).

Two questions:

1. Is there a pattern I can define that will do this?
2. Is there a way in the pattern to also single out and skip an entire module?

I tried to use Test Kind of type "Pattern" with a pattern of src/test/* but it tells me no tests found in default module. I must be misunderstanding

Comment: I've updated the 3rd paragraph in my question to explain why the methods in the other question don't address my situation. In the other question, the submitter has the luxury of a different naming pattern to key off of.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  - I immediately updated this explaining why it wasn't a duplicate. Why has the duplicate status not been removed?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, thank you very much for unmarking this as a duplicate. I appreciate it.